# Bootstrap toggle buttons inside popover content not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover, togglebutton

I have made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KrishnaAraty/ZVak6/1/) where i use twitter bootstrap toggle buttons & popover.

HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-toggle">
  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-info">On</button>
  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary active">Off</button>
</div>

<button id="popbutton" class="btn btn-lg btn-warn">pop up</button>
```

JS:

```
var popupElement = '<div class="btn-group btn-toggle"><button class="btn btn-sm btn-  info">On</button><button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary active">Off</button></div>';

$('#popbutton').popover({
  animation: true,
  content: popupElement,
  html: true
});


$('.btn-toggle').click(function () {
   $(this).find('.btn').toggleClass('active');

   if ($(this).find('.btn-primary').size() > 0) {
      $(this).find('.btn').toggleClass('btn-primary');
   }
   if ($(this).find('.btn-danger').size() > 0) {
      $(this).find('.btn').toggleClass('btn-danger');
   }
   if ($(this).find('.btn-success').size() > 0) {
      $(this).find('.btn').toggleClass('btn-success');
   }
   if ($(this).find('.btn-info').size() > 0) {
      $(this).find('.btn').toggleClass('btn-info');
   }

  $(this).find('.btn').toggleClass('btn-default');

});
```

The toggle button works, but when i use the same buttons inside a popover, it won't work.

Please suggest a method.

Comment: On the jsfiddle there's a console error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ; `, though I'm not sure if that is related

Comment: @Dan no it has nothing to do with that error .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since your popover buttons do not exist at load time you need to use event delegation. Also instead of `size()` (which is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8) you should use the `length` property:

```
$('body').on('click','.btn-toggle',function () {
    $(this).find('.btn').toggleClass('active');

    if ($(this).find('.btn-primary').length > 0) {
        $(this).find('.btn').toggleClass('btn-primary');
    }
    if ($(this).find('.btn-danger').length > 0) {
        $(this).find('.btn').toggleClass('btn-danger');
    }
    if ($(this).find('.btn-success').length > 0) {
        $(this).find('.btn').toggleClass('btn-success');
    }
    if ($(this).find('.btn-info').length > 0) {
        $(this).find('.btn').toggleClass('btn-info');
    }

    $(this).find('.btn').toggleClass('btn-default');
});
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/ZVak6/6/)**

Answer (score 2):

this is how you should do it , if you gonna append new elements to your page:

```
$('body').on('click','.btn-toggle',function() {

                $(this).find('.btn').toggleClass('active');

                if ($(this).find('.btn-primary').length > 0) {
                    $(this).find('.btn').toggleClass('btn-primary');
                }
                if ($(this).find('.btn-danger').length > 0) {
                    $(this).find('.btn').toggleClass('btn-danger');
                }
                if ($(this).find('.btn-success').length > 0) {
                    $(this).find('.btn').toggleClass('btn-success');
                }
                if ($(this).find('.btn-info').length > 0) {
                    $(this).find('.btn').toggleClass('btn-info');
                }

                $(this).find('.btn').toggleClass('btn-default');

            });
```

here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/prollygeek/ZVak6/5/